# Cartoon in which Donald Duck tries to stop another duck from committing suicide

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, animation

This is a cartoon I watched on English TV about a decade ago, maybe more. I have no idea when it was released but it can't have been much earlier than 1990, as the animation looked fairly modern. I don't think I caught the start of it and the only bit I clearly remember is the climax, but I'll try and describe that in as much detail as I can.

This was definitely a Donald Duck cartoon, or at least, Donald Duck was a major character in it. There was another duck character as well (a male), and by the climax of the cartoon this second duck had, for reasons I can't remember, become suicidally depressed. He erases himself with a pencil eraser, effectively committing suicide, but Donald Duck rushes over and uses the same pencil to draw him back into existence.

There then follows a brief tug-of-war, with the duck erasing himself and Donald re-drawing him again, until the duck angrily tells Donald to knock it off (I'm paraphrasing here). I don't really remember what happens after that, but I think Donald gathers the rest of the cartoon's cast and together they do *something* that restores the duck's will to live.

I'm not sure about this, but I vaguely recall that the altercation with the pencil takes place on a film set, or some other place with a lot of equipment - it's possible that the animation used the same "cartoon-characters-as-actors" conceit as "Who Framed Roger Rabbit". It may also have used live-action backgrounds, but I may be remembering it wrong.

I really hope this is enough for someone to identify it, because it's been bugging me for a little while now.

Comment: Can you check if it's this episode? http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Dennis_the_Duck_(House_of_Mouse_episode), It matches pretty good with your description =) Let me know if it is so I can add as an answer =)

Comment: It may well be that. The black-and-white elements match with my memory of what the background looked like during the pencil scene. I'll have a closer look when I get home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your description matches the episode *[Dennis the Duck](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Dennis_the_Duck_%28House_of_Mouse_episode%29)* from *House of Mouse*:

> It's Black-and-White Day at the House of Mouse, and the club is packed with old black and white cartoon characters. One of them, Dennis the Duck, tries to win over Donald, who is annoyed by him at first. No matter what Donald does, he can't get rid of Dennis, but then he has a change of heart when Dennis tries to kill himself.
>
> This episode has a dark moment in which Dennis tries to erase himself only to be saved by Donald. This is close to a suicide attempt, which is rather dark for a show like this.

Comment: I looked up the episode on YouTube myself without realizing it had already been linked here! Yes, this is definitely it!